# Maximum balanced binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, dynamic-programming

I am doing one question on dynamic programming where for a given height h, I have to calculate the maximum number of balanced binary trees. I have little confusion with base cases.

If the height is 0 then the number of balanced binary trees is 1 as for h=0 there is a root node only. But for h=1, I am not able to calculate the maximum number of balanced binary trees. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: what do you mean by **the number of balanced binary trees**? do you mean the number of nodes in the binary tree or the number of the sub-tree ?

Comment: Can you please remind us of your definition of a balanced binary tree?

Comment: The total number of balanced binary trees having height h.

Comment: A balanced Binary Tree is where each node has difference between heights of its left and right subtree less than equal to 1.

Comment: can you please answer my first question about: **what do you mean by the number of balanced binary trees?**

Comment: By "number of balanced binary trees" I mean all the balanced binary trees having height h because for a given height h there are multiple balanced binary trees

Answer (score 1):

The solution with a good explanation and figures can be found in:

- [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/count-balanced-binary-trees-of-height-h-in-cplusplus) with C plus plus code
- [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-balanced-binary-trees-height-h/) with different implementation.

For the special cases 0 and 1 :
**h=0 => nb = 1**, at the root, the height is 0, and we have only one node, hence 1 tree.
**h=1 => nb = 3**, this mean we have these possibilities:

- 1. Root node + only left child
- 2. Root node + only right child
- 3. Root node + left and right child

Hence, at h=1, we have 3 possible binary tree.

**h=2 => nb = 15**...etc.

Comment: The explanation that they have given are wrong because if height of a tree is 1 then it does not mean it has one node because for h=0 there is one node. There explanation is little twisted.

Comment: @AkhilSharma, their explanation and code work fine. the difference is only in the root, they consider the root at h=1, so in their code they check if h=0 or h=1 return 1. In your case you consider the root at height h=0; so you check only for h=0 return 1, else do the same recursion.  And yes, the height at the root should be 0, because the definition say  **The height of a node in a rooted tree is the number of edges in a maximal path **.  But this is not a big deal, a very small change (consider only 0) and it work the same. good luck.